# Filter Date using Date Picker in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have generated my crud screens using gii.. I have a search form, where i have put a date picker, where i give the user to select the date he wants.

But the problem is that i have the date stored in seconds in the database.

and i know that i can convert the date using strtotime. But then how do i filter using the search method in my model?

this is my date picker

```
<?php 
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(

        'name'=>'ordering_date',
        'id'=>'ordering_date',
        // additional javascript options for the date picker plugin
        'options'=>array(
            'showAnim'=>'fold',
        ),
        'htmlOptions'=>array(
            'style'=>'height:20px;'
        ),
        ));
    ?>
```

and this is my search method in my model. I want to compare the ordering_date

```
public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.
    //echo $this->ordering_date;
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('order_id',$this->order_id);
    $criteria->compare('customer_id',$this->customer_id);
    $criteria->compare('delivery_address_id',$this->delivery_address_id);
    $criteria->compare('billing_address_id',$this->billing_address_id);
    $criteria->compare('ordering_date',$this->ordering_date);
    $criteria->compare('ordering_done',$this->ordering_done,true);
    $criteria->compare('ordering_confirmed',$this->ordering_confirmed);
    $criteria->compare('payment_method',$this->payment_method);
    $criteria->compare('shipping_method',$this->shipping_method);
    $criteria->compare('comment',$this->comment,true);
    $criteria->compare('status',$this->status,true);
    $criteria->compare('total_price',$this->total_price);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
        'model'=>$model,
        'attribute'=>'ordering_date',
        'options'   => array('dateFormat' => 'mm-dd-yy',),
```

And search

```
$begindate = CDateTimeParser::parse($this->ordering_date, 'MM-dd-yyyy');
$enddate   = $begindate + 24* 60*60;
$criteria->addBetweenCondition('ordering_date', $begindate, $enddate);
```

Comment: `$this->ordering_date` gets its value from the input, therefore it is already in `mm-dd-yyy` format.

Answer (score 0):

Either do a `$this->ordering_date = strtotime($this->ordering_date);` before you compare or `$criteria->compare('ordering_date', strtotime($this->ordering_date));`

Comment: ya i did that!! i wasnt getting the result correctly. Then what i found out was that when u convert the date that u get from the date picker and compare with the database value, it gives different values, because when im storing the order date i consider the minutes and the seconds aswell. So i tried adding a condition to the criteria to get the values between the selected date and the next date. But then no results were given initially when u load the screen. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you storing the minutes/seconds if that only complicates things, plus you can't even filter by them? Just use 00 for hours/minutes/seconds.